# How can i sort a string in alphabetical order in python

Tags: python, function, alphabetical, alphabet

I've been trying to sort a string in alphabetical order and got stuck. I know that the sort function exists on python but i cant use it. Cant even use the .join method as well. Gotta do it all using for loops.

```
def wordOrder(word):
    word =  list(word)
    for i in range(0, len(word)):
        for j in range(i, len(word)):
            if word[i] > word[j]:
                word[i], word[j] = word[j], word[i]
    word = ""+ str(word)
    return word
```

Here's what i have but I did it with a tutor and cant remember what the if section does.
Thank you!

Comment: What's your actual question? The title asks how to sort, but the text just asks what 2 lines mean.

Comment: `str(word)` returns a string like `['a', 'b']`. If you want `ab` you need to use another loop that concatenates the letters to a string.

Comment: Sorry as this is my first post. I need to sort the string alphabettical but cant use the sort method. I added the line about the if statement confusion because this is a code that my tutor and i worked on and forgot what it meant.

Comment: You forgot what `if word[i] > word[j]:` means? It's just an ordinary `if` statement. It tests the condition, and if it's true it executes the code below it.

Comment: When you're sorting, you obviously have to compare the items that you're sorting, to see which is bigger then the other.

Comment: Ok my bad. I was not familiar with using lists on python but i get it now

Comment: Yes, it's the character at position `i` in the list. So you're comparing the characters at two places in the list. If the first is greater than the second one, you swap them.

Comment: this makes a lot of sense. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use ( > , < , <= , <= , == , != ) to compare two strings. Python compares string lexicographically i.e using ASCII value of the characters.

If statement compares the first and second letter's ASCII value.
if its greater than exchange.

for example,

```
print(wordOrder('ba'))

output
['a', 'b']
```

ASCII value of small `a` is `97` and `b` is `98`.

```
if word[i] > word[j]:
                word[i], word[j] = word[j], word[i]
```

So,

```
 word[i] --> b --> 98
 word[j]  --> a --> 97
```

Since, 98 is greater than 97 we swap both the values.

Comment: How do you know they only have ASCII characters?

Comment: Replace "Ascii value" with "character code"

Comment: this makes sense. the vizualization helped. thanks!

Comment: @Manuel, You can use ( > , < , <= , <= , == , !=  ) to compare two strings. Python compares string lexicographically i.e using ASCII value of the characters.

Comment: You can't compare ASCII values of non-ASCII characters. They don't have any.